# Angular js ui-router skipping $state.go

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

My AngularJs app is supposed to goto login page if the user is not logged in and try to load a path that requires an logged in user.

```
if ($localStorage.globals.access_token) {
    $rootScope.globals = $localStorage.globals;
    $state.go('app.dashboard-v1');
  }else{
    $state.go('access.signin)      
  }
```

whenever the apps loads this piece of code executes. The problem is when I tried to got to a path which requires a logged in user, instead of redirecting to login page, it goes to that specific path. whats even more confusing is that it start to change state to login page(access.signin) but never succeeds then starts the specific path(here i tried to access app.dashboad-v1 state by its url) then succeeding it. what I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you show us how that if statement is triggered?

Comment: Generally one aborts paths that requires a logged user by returning a rejected promise to the resolver function of the state. Use the `$stateChangeError` error event for UI-Router 0.x to go to the login page. For UI Router 1.x, use Transition Hooks. See [UI-Router Wiki - State Change Events](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events).

Comment: @BShaps i store the user credentials in a key attached to $localstorage. On Logout the key is cleared to empty object, so once the path is being reloaded this 'IF" conditions evaluates to false,since there is no key named 'access_token'.

Answer (score 0):

I finally corrected the issue. Returned a Promise to the "resolve" of the UI Router hence the transition failed and redirected to desired state(access.signin).